# Cannot achieve correct data packet on serial port every 100 mili sec (C#)

Tags: c#, serial-port, com-port

In my WPF app I set timer for write data with serialport every 100 mili sec. By every write data I recieve 160 bytes as one packet with `_serialPort.DataReceived += _serialPort_DataReceived;` but in 10 sec I should get 100 packets but I get only 80 packets.

When I set the `_readTimer.Interval = 10;` for send request to get data in 10 sec I get 98 - near the 100. What is the problem and how can I solve it by send the request every 100 mili sec.

```
public DataTransfer(SerialPort serialPort)
{
    _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 38400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    _readTimer = new Timer();
    _readTimer.Interval = 10;
    _readTimer.Elapsed += _readTimer_Elapsed;
    _readTimer.AutoReset = true;
    OpenSerialPort();
}

public void OpenSerialPort()
{

    _serialPort.Open();
    _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 50;
    _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 100;
    _serialPort.DataReceived += _serialPort_DataReceived;
    // Start the timer
    _readTimer.Start();

}

private void _readTimer_Elapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] temp = new byte[9];
    byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(560);
    temp = PacketIO.ReadRequest(data, PacketIO.Addr.Addr1);

    IsRead = true;
    _serialPort.BaseStream.BeginWrite(temp, 0, temp.Length, writeCallback, null);
    _unReadTimer.Start();
}

private void writeCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    _serialPort.BaseStream.EndWrite(ar);
}
```

Comment: It is _really_ appreciated to fix code formatting ;)

Comment: Why are you using a timer?  If you are using ASYNC methods there is no need for a timer.

Comment: The timer does not guarantee that it will not exceed 100ms. It guarantees that it will not enter in less than 100 ms. The longer the time, the greater your margin of error. You can check how many packets you have sent in a given time and perform incomplete sending if less than expected.

Comment: So how i can get packet excatly every 100ms?

Comment: What does `_serialPort_DataReceived` do? Have you considered switching this to `async` `await`?

Comment: `_serialPort_DataReceived` is the event of the Serialport Class for Receive data. it trigger when data send to us.

Comment: `timer.Interval` is in milliseconds, so your timer will run every *10ms* (unless there is some synchronization). There is no way to do things at precise times in c#, since the GC may run, or the OS may switch out your threads. The best you can do is get as close as possible. The alternative is a real time OS.  I would have expected a loop using read/write async, possibly with Thread.Sleep or Task.Delay to delay things. You might also want to read [some critisism of serialport](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)